# How can I install the ibm watson module?

Tags: ibm-watson, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to run IBM Watson's Natural Language Understanding in Python 3 but can't get the modules installed. This is what I started with:

```
import json 
from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1 
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator 
from ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features,EntitiesOptions, KeywordsOptions
```

The error message was:

> no module named ibm_watson

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have installed the latest version of the Watson Python SDK (it's 4.2.1 right now). For example, with pip:

```
pip install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=4.2.1"
```

See the [API reference](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding/natural-language-understanding?code=python) for more information and examples