# Python and IBM Watson SDK: ImportError: No module named ibm_watson

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, sentiment-analysis

I'm trying to use IBM Watson for sentiment analysis with Python, but I'm getting a *No module* error.

I followed the [docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/natural-language-understanding?code=python#sentiment) and my code looks like this:

```
import json
import constants
from ibm_watson import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
from ibm_watson.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, SentimentOptions


class SentimentAnalysis:
    
    def __init__(self):
        authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(constants.IBM_WATSON_KEY)
        this.natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
            version='2020-08-01',
            authenticator=authenticator
        )
        this.natural_language_understanding.set_service_url(constants.IBM_WATSON_URL)
    
    def analyse_sentiments(self, data):
        response = this.natural_language_understanding.analyze(
            url='www.wsj.com/news/markets',
            features=Features(sentiment=SentimentOptions(targets=['stocks']))).get_result()
        assert isinstance(response, object)
        return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sentiment_analysis_object = SentimentAnalysis()
    data = ("I've seen you")
    response = sentiment_analysis_object.analyse_sentiments(data)
    print json.dumps(response, indent=2)
```

Python version I'm using is Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: `ibm_watson` is a third-party module.  It does not come built in to python.  You have to install it yourself.  Did you do that?

Comment: Yeah I did. I used pip3 install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=4.6.0"

Comment: Is `pip3` the correct way to install modules for Anaconda?  I thought Anaconda had its own way to install modules.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. changed the command "conda install -c conda-forge ibm-watson" and still the same issue.

Comment: Please go through link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60127093/how-can-i-install-the-ibm-watson-module

Answer (score 0):

The home of the [IBM Watson Python SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk) is on GitHub. There you find a couple different ways of installing the Python module and to resolve issues.

That GitHub repo also has a directory with examples, including an [example for NLU](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples/natural_language_understanding_v1.py). Try running that.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

I have my `python` pointing to the `anaconda3` folder. So, when I run

```
which python
```

The output is

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python
```

> The same should be the case with `which python3`.

I uninstalled the existing `pip` installation of `ibm-watson` and ran the below command to install from `conda` packages

```
conda install -c conda-forge ibm-watson
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /usr/local/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - ibm-watson


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  ibm-watson         conda-forge/noarch::ibm-watson-4.7.0-pyh9f0ad1d_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: | WARNING conda.core.path_actions:verify(962): Unable to create environments file. Path not writable.
  environment location: /Users/VMac/.conda/environments.txt

done
Executing transaction: done
```

To confirm the installation, I ran the below command

```
conda list | grep ibm

ibm-cloud-sdk-core        1.5.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ibm-watson                4.7.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
```

I recommend uninstalling the previous versions of `ibm-watson` before installing the latest version.

```
pip uninstall ibm-watson
conda uninstall ibm-watson
```

Also, check whether you are pointing to the right version of python

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me, and the cause was that I had entered `source_file.py` at the command prompt instead of `python source_file.py`.